# db section in hopper

Tags: ios

There is a db section in hopper, which cause the code not being able to go to control follow graph mode
Do advise what cause this issue:

```
        ; Section __cstring
        ; Range: [0x10000a2c0; 0x10000a4d5[ (533 bytes)
        ; File offset : [41664; 42197[ (533 bytes)
        ; Flags: 0x2
        ;   S_CSTRING_LITERALS

                     aViewcontroller:
000000010000a2c0         db         "ViewController", 0                         ; DATA XREF=cfstring_ViewController
                     aStrongpwd123:
000000010000a2cf         db         "StrongPwd123", 0                           ; DATA XREF=cfstring_StrongPwd123
                     aWrongPassword:
000000010000a2dc         db         "WRONG PASSWORD", 0                         ; DATA XREF=cfstring_WRONG_PASSWORD
                     aError:
000000010000a2eb         db         "ERROR", 0                                  ; DATA XREF=cfstring_ERROR
                     aOk:
000000010000a2f1         db         "Ok", 0                                     ; DATA XREF=cfstring_Ok
                     aAdminviewcontr:
000000010000a2f4         db         "AdminViewController", 0
```

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  eLS_LogIn2
//
//  Created by litsnarf on 10/20/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 litsnarf. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AdminViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
        
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize password;

@synthesize pwd;
    


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    
    pwd = @"StrongPwd123";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    
}
```

Here is the actual implementation of the code

Comment: All those db are bytes that are defined  an ascii or unicode  strings  as in your other query why are you trying to disassemble DATA ?  find CODE that uses this data and disassemble the CODE